# Prolog. Count members in database or List

Tags: prolog

I have a database i want to write a query to return the total members in the database

```
member(paul,100). member(john,101). member(ryan,102). member(jabouki,103).
```

Should Return 4

I also have a list and i want to return the number of persons in the list

```
memberlist([ant,cat,sat,bat]).
```

Should Return 4

Query I have thus far that only return the items in the database and list.

```
member(MemberName,_).
memberlist(Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
findall(X, member(X,_), L), length(L,N).
```

Will give you the following results:

```
L = [paul, john, ryan, jabouki],
N = 4.
```

Greetings

Solick